# Put strings from JSON-encoded array into Java ArrayList

Tags: java, php, arrays, json, arraylist

I've created an array and have filled it with row values from an SQL database, and then encode the array into a JSON object:

```
$league = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
    $league[] = $leagueName;
}

json_encode($league);
```

How would I go about retrieving the items from the array, and then inserting them into an ArrayList? I currently have this in my Java code:

```
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Currently, "result" takes the format: `"["leagueA", "leagueB", "leagueC"]"`, where I would have liked to have seen something like `"[0:"leagueA", 1:"leagueB", 2:"leagueC"]"` so that I can have reference the returned values in a loop. Is there any way to insert the returned values into an `ArrayList` without manually parsing returned "result"?

Comment: your current result have those indexes 0,1,2. `["leagueA", "leagueB", "leagueC"]` means `Array('0'=>"leagueA".......)`

Comment: Well, in json, you either got an array (your first example) or you got an object (key: value) which is your second example (except from that it then would be surrounded by `{}`) . But you should be able to fetch values from your first example by `array[0]`, `array[1]` as well. The indexes: 0, 1, 2...etc are implicit.

Comment: Create a `JSONArray` instead and just iterate over the elements. With a simple for statement, you'll have access to indices.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this worked for me. I didn't know that the string "result" was in a format that would allow me to use a JSONArray. After I created a JSONArray I was able to iterate over it and add to an ArrayList. thanks for your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by simply creating a JSONArray (instead of JSONObject) like so:

```
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            //JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if(jsonArray.length() == 0){
                returnedLeague = null;
            }
            else{
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    returnedLeague.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                }
            }
```

Turns out, a JSONArray can be created from a string if it is properly formatted, which the json_encode function did for me.